# Is it possible to aggregate document returning from "find and update"?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Imagine I have two collections as below:

**Students**

```
{
  "_id": "1234",
  "name": "Theodo"
}
```

**Card**

```
{
  "student_id": "1234",
  "given_date": "11.10.2019"
}
```

And then I need to update the student like this;

```
db.students.find_one_and_update({"_id": "1234"}, {"$set":{"name": "Matt"}}, return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

This is cool and it returns this;

```
[
    {
      "_id": "1234",
      "name": "Matt"
    }
]
```

But imagine the UI needs the information like this;

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1234",
    "card_given_date": "11.10.2019",
    "name": "Matt"
  }
]
```

So I need to retrieve it with an aggregation;

```
db.students.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "cards",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "student_id",
      "as": "student_card"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$student_card"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "card_given_date": "$student_card.given_date"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "student_card"
  }
])
```

*test aggregation*: https://mongoplayground.net/p/UlTGnXA2Rkx

And my question is; I have to update, then retrieve it with an aggregation. If I can get the document after `update` operation, is there anything I can do to aggregate the returned document, so that I get rid of second `retrieve` operation?

Answer (score 1):

In principle you can do this, if you run MongoDB version > 5.1

```
let newDoc = db.students.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: "1234" },
   { $set: { "name": "Matt" } },
   { returnNewDocument: true }
)

db.aggregate([
   { $documents: [newDoc] },
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "cards",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "student_id",
         as: "student_card"
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$student_card" },
   {
      $set: {
         card_given_date: "$student_card.given_date",
         student_card: "$$REMOVE"
      }
   }
])
```

But I don't know whether `db.aggregate([ { $documents: ... } ])` is supported with python.

Comment: It looks better even though we still need to call a second function "aggregation", after "findOneAndUpdate", but we don't spend time to find the same object again so this looks better.